# Solr: Query substring match

Tags: solr

We receive a comma-separated list of keywords like so:

1. `brand tv, phone, tablet`
2. `brand`
3. `technology, phone`

Each of above items will correspond to a Solr document. What we want to achieve is the following behavior:

- Searching for `brand` will return item 2.
- Searching for `brand tv` will return items 1 and 2.
- Searching for `grey brand tv` will return items 1 and 2.
- Searching for `foo bar brand tv baz` will return items 1 and 2.
- Searching for `phone case` will return items 1 and 3.

We tried to achieve this with...

... on the index end:

- `<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>`

... on the query end:

- `<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>`
- `<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" tokenSeparator=" "/>`

But that doesn't work as we want to. Also no matter on how high we set the `maxShingleSize` to there could always be cases just above that limit...

Answer (score 0):

We ended up just shingling the input on the client end and are searching for an exact match in those shingles. Since our keywords rarely consist of more than 3 words, we shingle up to 3 words.

**Example:**
When the search query is "brand tv grey" we search for `keywords:("brand" OR "tv" OR "grey" OR "brand tv" OR "tv grey" OR "brand tv grey")`.

---

**Alternative approach (untested) - maybe helpful for others**

Above behavior might be achievable by introducing [Querqy](https://github.com/querqy/querqy) and using [decorate rules](https://docs.querqy.org/querqy/rewriters/common-rules.html#decorate-rules).